# Get value of every nth row from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets, SheetA and SheetB.

SheetB has a cycle of 7 rows of data, followed by 1 row averaging the previous 7 row of data, i.e.

[image: SheetB Example]

I am looking for a formula that I can use on SheetA to grab only the averages from SheetB; that is, a formula that will produce the below output for *any* number of cycles (not just the two shown above)

[image: SheetA Example]

The .csv for SheetB, if needed:

```
,,,,
,Day,Fruit,Quantity,Eaten
,3/7/21,Banana,42,24
,3/8/21,Banana,23,6
,3/9/21,Banana,42345,553
,3/10/21,Banana,12,6
,3/11/21,Banana,44,11
,3/12/21,Banana,77,66
,3/13/21,Banana,234,42
Weekly Average,,,6111,101.1428571
,3/14/21,Banana,123,4
,3/15/21,Banana,5326,5
,3/16/21,Banana,234656,6
,3/17/21,Banana,231,7
,3/18/21,Banana,5,8
,3/19/21,Banana,23423,9
,3/20/21,Banana,758,10
Weekly Average,,,37788.85714,7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the setup you've shown, try this:

```
=FILTER(SheetB!D:E,SheetB!A:A="Weekly Average")
```

Comment: Could you modify this to fit the two-sheet example?

Comment: See formula change.